# Why can't I create a basic window with Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

My `app.js` file is:

```
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#fff');

// create tab group
//var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();


//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'TAB 1',
    backgroundColor:'#f00'
});

win1.addEventListener('click',function()
        {
            // set background color back to white after tab group transition
            alert('#fff');
        });
```

and all that loads is the red "Powered by Titanium" screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to open the window

```
win1.open();
```